# Using command line to enable proxy

Tags: powershell, command-line, proxy, netsh, proxy-server

I'd like to use command line or Powershell to enable "Use setup script" and set the "Script address". Here's the picture: [Enable automatic proxy setup Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCKvy.png) , or enable "Use a proxy server" and set "Address". Here's the picture: [Enable manual proxy setup picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1dFN.png)

I tried the commands below, but the proxy doesn't enable. The proxy server shows `off`, as shows here: [Fail to enable proxy setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bd5HK.png)

```
netsh winhttp set proxy IP-address "10.0.0.6:8080"
```

```
netsh winhttp set proxy proxy-server="10.0.0.6:8080" bypass-list = "*.***.com"
```

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyServer /t REG_SZ /d 10.1.1.1:3128 /f
```

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

Questions: I'd like to enable proxy setup using command line or Powershell. Does anyone have the idea?

If there is something confused, I'd like to explain more.

Thanks.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: One potential problem: There probably shouldn't be spaces around `=` after `bypass-list` (and, of course, you must supply actual values in your arguments; I assume your showing only placeholders).

Comment: @mklement0 Sure. I'll format my post. Thanks for telling  me. Thanks for your suggestions. I'll try to remove "=" and give the value. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that your edit to improve formatting actually made things worse.

Comment: @mklement0 I improved the formatting. Is that correct now? Besides, I try to use the command line:  ```netsh winhttp set proxy proxy-server="10.0.0.6:8080" bypass-list "*.***.com" ```, but it shows: ```Usage:  set proxy [proxy-server=]<server name> [bypass-list=]<hosts list>```. It seems that it need ```=```. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you need `=`, but try _without spaces_: `netsh winhttp set proxy proxy-server="10.0.0.6:8080" bypass-list="*.***.com"`. While this should resolve a potential _syntax_ problem; I have no idea if the command will work as intended, as I am not familiar with it. As a general tip: it is often necessary to log off and log back on again (or reboot) after directly manipulating the registry.